# Group by Month, return 0 if no record found

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to fetch records from database table for last 12 months. Here is what I tried so far.

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id), date_part('month', s.viewed_at) month_number
    FROM statistics_maps_view as s
    INNER JOIN maps as m
    ON s.maps_id=m.id Where m.users_id = $users_id group by month_number ORDER BY month_number DESC LIMIT 12
```

I know It'll group the records month wise. but is there a way to add `Count = 0` if there is no record for a particular month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `group by` clause will not create entries where there's no data, as you've seen. What you could do is `left join` this entire result with another result set that has all the entries you want - e.g., one you dynamically generate with [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-srf.html):

```
SELECT    generate_series AS month_number, cnt
FROM      GENERATE_SERIES(1,12) g
LEFT JOIN (SELECT     COUNT(s.id) AS cnt, 
                      DATE_PART('month', s.viewed_at) AS month_number
           FROM       statistics_maps_view s
           INNER JOIN maps m ON s.maps_id = m.id 
           WHERE      m.users_id = $users_id 
           GROUP BY   month_number) s ON g.generate_series = s.month_number
ORDER BY  1 ASC
```